# jquery and css3 slider works one direction but not the other

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I have my code now allowing my to have an item slide to the left out of view and be deleted. My problem is that once I have deleted that element I create another element on the right side off the screen that I want to have slide in once the the original element has been removed.

What it is doing now is once the element has been deleted, the right elements appears in the center with out the animation.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Slider View</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .leftRemove{
                left: -3000px;
            }
            .rightAdd{
                position: relative;
                right: -3000px;
                transition: right 2s;
                -webkit-transition: right 2s;
            }
            .centerFocus{
                position: relative;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                right: 0px;
                background-color: green;
                transition: left 2s;
                -webkit-transition: left 2s;
            }                   

        </style>
        <script>
        $(document).on('click', '#main', function(){
            $('body').append("<div class='rightAdd'>Hello!</div>");
            $( "#main" ).addClass('leftRemove');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.leftRemove').remove();
                $('.rightAdd').attr('id', 'main');
                }, 800);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $( "#main" ).removeClass('rightAdd');
                $( "#main" ).addClass('centerFocus');
                }, 1000);
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='main' class='centerFocus'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that `right` is a valid `css` property.  To move something to the right give `left` a positive value.  I also moved your appended `hello` so that the transition worked smoother.

Try this:

```
        .rightAdd{
            position: relative;
            left: 1000px;
            transition: right 2s;
            -webkit-transition: right 2s;
        }


       $(document).on('click', '#main', function(){
        $( "#main" ).addClass('leftRemove');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.leftRemove').remove();
            $('body').append("<div class='rightAdd'>Hello!</div>");
            $('.rightAdd').attr('id', 'main');
            }, 800);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $( "#main" ).removeClass('rightAdd');
            $( "#main" ).addClass('centerFocus');
            }, 1000);
    });
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/9CGUU/

**Update**

I was seeing the `Hello!` flicker on my screen when I had the fiddle in fullscreen.  This update fixed that for me.

```
 setTimeout(function(){
            $('.leftRemove').remove();
            $('body').append("<div class='rightAdd'></div>");
            $('.rightAdd').attr('id', 'main');
 }, 800);
 setTimeout(function(){
            $( "#main" ).removeClass('rightAdd');
            $('#main').html('Hello!');
            $( "#main" ).addClass('centerFocus');
 }, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9CGUU/6/

Comment: Thats what I was looking for. I appreciate you optimizing the code as well.

Comment: @user1753797 Your welcome.. I was just looking and the `Hello!` flickers a little bit on full screen.  This example is better.  http://jsfiddle.net/9CGUU/6/